# Is conversion of energy into time and space possible ?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

In classic mechanics mass and energy were constant dimensions. Relativistic mechanics stated that 'energy and mass' together is conserved by using conservation of energy.But cant we say that energy is converted to time and space further? In space-time graph blanket, if energy is third axis , we can see gravitational field as depression in blanket. So , indirectly we see a relation between energy, space and time. If energy is converted into time and space , a specific part in every energy transformation might cause the space and time extend. Is such an phenomenom possible ?

Comment: -1 because this question makes no sense. How do you claim that mass/energy are dimensions? What makes you think that space and time are entities we can convert things into?

Comment: Also, the *blanket with things on it* view is just an analogy for GR, because its *difficult* to visualize 4 dimensional spacetime. The analogy is often misleading.

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly a relationship between energy and spacetime, and indeed this is what Einstein's equation tells us:

$$ G_{\alpha\beta} = 8\pi T_{\alpha\beta} $$

where the quantity on the left, $G_{\alpha\beta}$, is the [Einstein tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_tensor) that describes the geometry of spacetime and the quantity on the right, $T_{\alpha\beta}$, is [the stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) that describes the mass/energy distribution.

However, in general relativity there is no interconversion of energy and spacetime. The two are related but different and you can't convert mass/energy to spacetime or vice versa.